# How to print date using logger info

Tags: python-2.7

This code does not print anything:

```
logger.info('Some Strings '+ date + ', '+ date)
```

Comment: I think this will be helpful : https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/minimal-example.html

Answer (score 0):

To print variables as strings try `.format` ;) In your case the statement would look like this:

```
 logger.info('Some Strings {1}, {2}'.format(date, date))
```

Also you can take a look at this resource : https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

And look [here](https://pyformat.info/) to find out what you can do with `.format`